# Dowload Files from remote server using phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

I am using the following code from the phpseclib library to login to remote server (Remote server uses: SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol):

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('200.160.163.10');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
?>
```

After running the above code I get the following message:

```
Notice: Error reading channel data in /home/comdinhe/public_html/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3480

Notice: Connection closed prematurely in /home/comdinhe/public_html/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3500

Login Failed
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Log: http://pastebin.com/j9M7tZAM

Comment: Can you post the SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then `echo $ssh->getLog();` before the `exit`.

Comment: Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/j9M7tZAM

Comment: That connection is taking a while. It's taking the server 20s to get the `NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS` packet and then 10s for the `NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST` packet to be sent and another 20s for the `NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA` packet to be sent. idk why it's taking so long but since it is try doing `$sftp->setTimeout(999999)` or some such.

Comment: By setting up Timeout to 999999 the error message is gone. However I am still not able to copy the file. And no other error message is shown.

Comment: Can you post a new log file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **get** method is for Net_SFTP.

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('200.160.585.10');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->get(
    '/sianbima/cbfundo/cbfundo_00000_20160808_171429.txt',
    '/home/comdinhe/public_html/testeArquivo.txt'
);
?>
```

Or you can try execute the rsync command in the ssh.

```
$ssh->exec('rsync -avz /sianbima/cbfundo/cbfundo_00000_20160808_171429.txt /home/comdinhe/public_html');
```

Comment: When I try to use 'Net_SFTP' I am not able to login I get the following message: 'Notice: Error reading channel data in /home/comdinhe/public_html/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3480'. When I try to use $ssh->exec nothing happens.

Comment: Now see what returns in `echo $sftp->isAuthenticated() . $sftp->isConnected() .  "\r\n";`